# How can i display Current Location in Android Google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, currentlocation

I want display Current location of the devices in Google maps how can i do it i am displying the normal map now .the following code display Lat and Lang positions of the devices how can i display the Adress in the map by using that lat and lang postions .

```
package com.appulento.mapsexample.pack;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

    public class MapsMianClass extends  MapActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



            /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
            LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
            mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
          }

          /* Class My Location Listener */
          public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
          {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
            {
              loc.getLatitude();
              loc.getLongitude();

              String Text = "My current location is: " +
              "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
              "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

              Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
            {
              Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
            {
              Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
            {

            }

          }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }


      }
```

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: why dont you just look at the right bottom of this page ..and click on links given in **Related**

Answer (score 2):

Since this question has been here for over a year, the method of displaying maps on Android has changed.

After you've got your current location (lat & long), all you need to do is to pass this coordinate to a map marker.

Here's the snippet I copy & pasted from [Google Maps Android API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker) Documentation:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Hello world"));
```

As for how to use Google Maps, they've also got a complete guide in the documentation.

I pasted the link of full steps here to save you a leg:

[Google Maps Android API V2 - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

If you carefully follow the steps there, you should display the maps and showing markers without any problems.

Here's one more thing you may need to pay attention to: when enable the Google Maps option inside the API Console, please make sure you're enabling **Google Maps Android API V2**, and please also make sure that you've chosen the correct certificate while retrieving the API key.

Hope this could help you getting out of the mist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Acquire GPS location.
2. Draw an icon (or a marker) on the map to the GPS location.
3. Move map so that current location is visible.

Please tell which step causes problems.

Comment: i am facing the problem in moving the map to current location am getting the lat and lang positions .just now i edited my latest code

Answer (score 0):

Use reverse Geo encoding to convert those latlngs into an address, and then you can either use a text view or a Toast to display that address.
This link might be helpful.
http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Displaying-Current-Location-on-Google-Maps